# Put all hashmap together based on same name condition in java 8

Tags: java, collections, java-8, java-stream

```
public class PersonAgg {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Person> persons = new ArrayList<>();
        Map<String, Integer> age = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Integer> age2 = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Integer> age3 = new HashMap<>();
        Map<String, Integer> age4 = new HashMap<>();
        age.put("One", 1);
        age2.put("Two", 2);
        age3.put("Three", 3);
        age4.put("Four", 4);
        persons.add(new Person("Ajay", age));
        persons.add(new Person("Vijay", age2));
        persons.add(new Person("Ajay", age3));
        persons.add(new Person("Vijay", age4));

    }

}

class Person {

    public Person(String name, Map<String, Integer> age) {
        super();
        this.name = name;
        this.age = age;
    }

    private String name;
    private Map<String, Integer> age;
```

Now I want output like : `{name : Ajay, HashMapValue : {age :["One",1],} age3 :["Three",3]}, {name : Vijay , HashMapValue : {age2 :["Two",2],} age4 :["Four",4]}`

Comment: It's always clear from the question when it states what you have tried. Gives a good amount of problem-solving space to others and self to know more about it. On a different note, you are looking "to group elements based on a key", if that can help you search things around.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this:

```
Map<String, Map<String, Integer>> grouped = persons.stream()
    .collect(toMap(Person::getName, Person::getAge, (p1, p2) -> {
        p1.putAll(p2);
        return p1;
    }));
```

Comment: Thanks for suggestions but the output result you mentioned is not required which I want output result is : [{"name":"Ajay","age":[{"One":1}, {"Three":3}]},
                           {"name":"Vijay","age":[{"Two":2},"age":{"Four":4}}]

Comment: As I understood you want to group by odd and even age? Also, it's not clear by which parameter you want to group.

Comment: No I don't want to group by odd and even age. I just want to group by person name like : Ajay and Vijay and group all their Hashmap together.

Answer (score 0):

Not perfect So please feel free to improve upon this answer

```
public class Test
{
 public static void main(String args[])
 {
  List<Person> persons=List.of(new Person("Ajay",Map.of("One",1))
                              ,new Person("Vijay",Map.of("Two",2))
                              ,new Person("Ajay",Map.of("Three",3))
                              ,new Person("Vijay",Map.of("Four",4)));

  Map<String,List<String>> values=                     
                               persons.stream()
                              .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(p->" name : "+p.name+", HashMapValue: ",
                                       Collectors.mapping(p2->p2.age.entrySet().stream(),
                                       Collectors.flatMapping(ages->ages.map(entry->get(entry))
                                      ,Collectors.toList())))
                                    );


  System.out.println("{");
  values.entrySet().forEach((value)->
  {
   System.out.print(value.getKey());
   value.getValue().forEach((age)->System.out.print(age+","));
   System.out.println();
  });
  System.out.println("}");
 }

 private static String get(Entry<String,Integer> entry)
 {
  String map;

  switch(entry.getKey())
  {
   case "One":map="age";
   break;
   case "Two":map="age2";
   break;
   case "Three":map="age3";
   break;
   default:map="age4";
  }

  return map+" :["+entry.getKey()+","+entry.getValue()+"]";
 }

 private static class Person
 {
  private final String name;
  private final Map<String,Integer> age;

  private Person(String name,Map<String,Integer> age)
  {
   this.name=name;
   this.age=age;
  }
 }
```

Output:

```
{
 name : Ajay, HashMapValue: age :[One,1],age3 :[Three,3],
 name : Vijay, HashMapValue: age2 :[Two,2],age4 :[Four,4],
}
```